# Getting error while inserting test data in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have developed below test class but not getting why i am getting below error,

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object..

the id i am passing has having the value..any suggestion?

**insert RSMObj;** getting error at this line...

**apex class:**

```
public class GSDPartnerCloneWithSkillsController {

public ApexPages.StandardController controller {get; set;}
public GSD_Partner__c GSDP {get;set;}
public ID newRecordId {get;set;}
public Id OldGSDResourceId {get;set;}
public Id NewGSDResourceId {get;set;}


public GSDPartnerCloneWithSkillsController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    this.controller = controller;
    GSDP = (GSD_Partner__c)controller.getRecord();

}

public PageReference cloneWithItems() {

     Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
     GSD_Partner__c newGSDP;

     try {

         //GSDP = (GSD_Partner__c) GSDDataUtility.getObject('GSD_Partner__c', GSDP.id);
         List<GSD_Partner__c> InsertGSDPList = new List<GSD_Partner__c>();
         List<GSD_Partner__c> GSDPList = [SELECT supervisor__c,Queue_Suffix__c,case_exchange_identifier__c,quota_factor__c,minimum_assignments_monthly__c,open_all_hours__c,account__c,country_iso__c,notes__c,portfolio__c,maximum_assignments_daily__c,createdbyid,lastmodifieddate,id,phone__c,portal_user_identifier__c,last_daily_counter_reset__c,logistics_badge_id__c,name,isdeleted,queue__c,resource__c,systemmodstamp,provider_type__c,last_monthly_counter_reset__c,does_diagnosis__c,email__c,send_case_exchange_reminders__c,mru_code__c,createddate,can_see_quotes__c,ownerid,assignment_counter_daily__c,country_name__c,active__c,case_exchange_enabled__c,assignment_counter_monthly__c,does_own_logistics_and_parts__c,engagement_method__c,maximum_assignments_monthly__c,lastmodifiedbyid,currencyisocode,commitment_levels__c FROM GSD_Partner__c WHERE Id = :GSDP.id];
         for(GSD_Partner__c GSDP : GSDPList ){
             newGSDP = GSDP.clone(false);
             newGSDP.Queue_Suffix__c = 'Enter Unique value';
             InsertGSDPList.add(newGSDP);
         } 
         insert InsertGSDPList;

         if(!InsertGSDPList.isEmpty()){
             newRecordId = InsertGSDPList[0].id;
         }

         GSD_Resource__c OldGSDResource = [select id from  GSD_Resource__c where Partner__c = :GSDP.id limit 1];
         OldGSDResourceId = OldGSDResource.id;
         system.debug('OldGSDResourceId :'+OldGSDResourceId );

         GSD_Resource__c NewGSDResource = [select id from  GSD_Resource__c where Partner__c = :newRecordId  limit 1];
         NewGSDResourceId = NewGSDResource.id;
         system.debug('NewGSDResourceId :'+NewGSDResourceId);

         CLoneGSDResourceLang();
         CLoneGSDResourceNon();
         CLoneGSDResourcePPS();
         CLoneGSDResourcePMaster();
         CLoneGSDResourceServices();
         CLoneGSDResourceTech();

     } catch (Exception e){
        Database.rollback(sp);
        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        return null;
     }

    return new PageReference('/'+newGSDP.id+'/e?retURL=%2F'+newGSDP.id);
}

public void CLoneGSDResourceLang(){

    List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> InsertnewSkillList = new List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c>();
    List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> SkillsList = [select id,Skill_Name__c,Skill_Category__c,Standard__c,Stand_By__c,Non_Product_Skill_Level__c,Web_App_Resp_Created_Dt__c,Web_App_Resp_Modified_Dt__c,Responsibility_Skill_Level__c,Web_App_Employee_Id__c,Web_App_ID__c,Web_App_Skill_Id__c from GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c where Skill_Category__c = :Label.GSDResourceLang and Resource_ID__c = :OldGSDResourceId];  
    if(!SkillsList.isEmpty()){
        for (GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c GSDrskill : SkillsList) {
              GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c newGSDrskill  = GSDrskill.clone(false);
              newGSDrskill.Resource_ID__c = NewGSDResourceId;
              InsertnewSkillList.add(newGSDrskill);
        }
        system.debug('InsertnewSkillList:'+InsertnewSkillList);
        insert InsertnewSkillList ;
    }
}

public void CLoneGSDResourceNon(){

    List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> InsertnewSkillList = new List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c>();
    List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> SkillsList = [select id,Skill_Name__c,Skill_Category__c,Standard__c,Stand_By__c,Non_Product_Skill_Level__c,Web_App_Resp_Created_Dt__c,Web_App_Resp_Modified_Dt__c,Responsibility_Skill_Level__c,Web_App_Employee_Id__c,Web_App_ID__c,Web_App_Skill_Id__c from GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c where Skill_Category__c = :Label.GSDResourceNon and Resource_ID__c = :OldGSDResourceId];  
    if(!SkillsList.isEmpty()){
        for (GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c GSDrskill : SkillsList) {
              GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c newGSDrskill  = GSDrskill.clone(false);
              newGSDrskill.Resource_ID__c = NewGSDResourceId;
              InsertnewSkillList.add(newGSDrskill);
        }
        system.debug('InsertnewSkillList:'+InsertnewSkillList);
        insert InsertnewSkillList ;
    }
}

public void CLoneGSDResourcePPS(){

    List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> InsertnewSkillList = new List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c>();
    List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> SkillsList = [select id,Skill_Name__c,Skill_Category__c,Standard__c,Stand_By__c,Non_Product_Skill_Level__c,Web_App_Resp_Created_Dt__c,Web_App_Resp_Modified_Dt__c,Responsibility_Skill_Level__c,Web_App_Employee_Id__c,Web_App_ID__c,Web_App_Skill_Id__c from GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c where Skill_Category__c = :Label.GSDResourcePPS and Resource_ID__c = :OldGSDResourceId];  
    if(!SkillsList.isEmpty()){
        for (GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c GSDrskill : SkillsList) {
              GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c newGSDrskill  = GSDrskill.clone(false);
              newGSDrskill.Resource_ID__c = NewGSDResourceId;
              InsertnewSkillList.add(newGSDrskill);
        }
        system.debug('InsertnewSkillList:'+InsertnewSkillList);
        insert InsertnewSkillList ;
    }
}

public void CLoneGSDResourcePMaster(){

    List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> InsertnewSkillList = new List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c>();
    List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> SkillsList = [SELECT Id, Name, Skill_Name__r.Name, Responsibility_Skill_Level__c, Skill_Name__r.Product_Description__c, Skill_Name__r.Portfolio__c FROM GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c WHERE Resource_ID__c = :OldGSDResourceId AND Skill_Category__c =: Label.GSDResourcePMaster ];
    if(!SkillsList.isEmpty()){
        for (GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c GSDrskill : SkillsList) {
              GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c newGSDrskill  = GSDrskill.clone(false);
              newGSDrskill.Resource_ID__c = NewGSDResourceId;
              InsertnewSkillList.add(newGSDrskill);
        }
        system.debug('InsertnewSkillList:'+InsertnewSkillList);
        insert InsertnewSkillList ;
    }
}

public void CLoneGSDResourceServices(){

    List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> InsertnewSkillList = new List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c>();
    List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> SkillsList = [SELECT Id, Name, Skill_Name__r.Name, Responsibility_Skill_Level__c, Skill_Name__r.Product_Description__c, Skill_Name__r.Portfolio__c, Skill_Name__r.Support_Activity__c,Standard__c, Stand_By__c FROM GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c WHERE Resource_ID__c = :OldGSDResourceId AND Skill_Category__c ='Services' ];
    if(!SkillsList.isEmpty()){
        for (GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c GSDrskill : SkillsList) {
              GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c newGSDrskill  = GSDrskill.clone(false);
              newGSDrskill.Resource_ID__c = NewGSDResourceId;
              InsertnewSkillList.add(newGSDrskill);
        }
        system.debug('InsertnewSkillList:'+InsertnewSkillList);
        insert InsertnewSkillList ;
    }
}

public void CLoneGSDResourceTech(){

    List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> InsertnewSkillList = new List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c>();
    List<GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c> SkillsList = [SELECT Id, Name, Responsibility_Skill_Level__c, Skill_Name__r.Name, Skill_Name__r.Technologies_Name__c FROM GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c WHERE Resource_ID__c =:OldGSDResourceId  AND Skill_Category__c =: Label.GSDResourceTech ];
    if(!SkillsList.isEmpty()){
        for (GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c GSDrskill : SkillsList) {
              GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c newGSDrskill  = GSDrskill.clone(false);
              newGSDrskill.Resource_ID__c = NewGSDResourceId;
              InsertnewSkillList.add(newGSDrskill);
        }
        system.debug('InsertnewSkillList:'+InsertnewSkillList);
        insert InsertnewSkillList ;
    }
    }
   }
```

**test class:**

```
 @isTest
 public class GSDPartnerCloneWithSkillsController_Test{

private testMethod static void TestMethod1(){

    Global_Config__c GCObj=new Global_Config__c (CPQ_Mute_Validation_Rule__c=false,DPlus_Mute_Validation_Rule__c=true,Mute_Triggers__c=true,
                                                    Mute_Validation_Rule__c=true,Mute_Workflow_Rule__c=true,Name='GSD');

    insert GCOBJ;


    HPTriggerFrameworkObjectMapping__c PartCSObj= new HPTriggerFrameworkObjectMapping__c(name='GSD_Partner__c',DispatcherCalssName__c='GSDPartnerProfile');
    insert PartCSObj;

    HPTriggerFrameworkObjectMapping__c ResCSObj= new HPTriggerFrameworkObjectMapping__c(name='GSD_Resource__c',DispatcherCalssName__c='GSDNewResource');
    insert ResCSObj;

    HPTriggerFrameworkObjectMapping__c SKMObj= new HPTriggerFrameworkObjectMapping__c(name='GSD_Skill_Master__c',DispatcherCalssName__c='GSDSKillMaster');
    insert SKMObj;

    HPTriggerFrameworkObjectMapping__c RSKMMObj= new HPTriggerFrameworkObjectMapping__c(name='GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c',DispatcherCalssName__c='GSDResourceSkillMapping');
    insert RSKMMObj;

    Profile fsmManagerPro= [Select Id, Name from Profile where Name = 'GSD FSM Sub Regional Resource' limit 1];        

    User fsmProfileUser= new User( profileId = fsmManagerPro.id, username = 'testemail22@hp.com', email = 'testemail22@hp.com', 
                emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8', localesidkey = 'en_US',languagelocalekey = 'en_US', timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                alias='cspu22', lastname='lastname', Adoption_Role_Type__c = 'IT', Email_Address__c = 'testemail3@hp.com',Legacy_Employee_Ref__c='12345', 
                RMR_Primary_Operational_Role__c = 'Solution Architect');

    insert fsmProfileUser;

    World_Region__c WR=new World_Region__c();
    wr.Name='US';
    insert WR;



    RecordType rt = [select id,Name from RecordType where SobjectType='Account' and Name='Partner' Limit 1];
    account aObj=new account(name='Account1',RecordTypeId=rt.id,MDCP_Business_Relationship_ID__c = 'abc',World_Region1__c=wr.id);
    insert aObj;

    PageReference pref = Page.GSDpartnerClone;
    Test.setCurrentPage(pref);

    Gsd_partner__c pObj=new Gsd_partner__c(name='partnerEx1',Account__c = aObj.id,Phone__c='9739',Email__c='xyz@hp.com',Queue_Suffix__c='queue1');
    insert pObj;

    Apexpages.StandardController sc = new Apexpages.standardController(pObj);
    GSDPartnerCloneWithSkillsController PCObj=new GSDPartnerCloneWithSkillsController(sc);

    Test.startTest();

    GSD_Resource__c oldresource = [Select Id From GSD_Resource__c  where Partner__c = :pObj.id];
    system.debug('oldresource :'+oldresource);

    GSD_Skill_Master__c SMObj= new GSD_Skill_Master__c();
    SMObj.Skill_Name__c = 'testskillname';
    SMObj.Skill_Type__c='Non-Product';
    SMObj.Skill_Category__c='Language';
    SMObj.Name='German';
    insert SMObj;

    GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c RSMObj = new GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c();
    RSMObj.Skill_Name__c=SMObj.id;
    RSMObj.Standard__c=true;
    RSMObj.Stand_By__c=true;
    RSMObj.Non_Product_Skill_Level__c='0';
    RSMObj.Responsibility_Skill_Level__c='3';
    RSMObj.Skill_Category__c='Language';
    RSMObj.Resource_ID__c= oldresource.id;
    system.debug('RSMObj :'+RSMObj);
    **insert RSMObj;**

    PageReference ref = PCObj.cloneWithItems();


    PageReference redir = new PageReference('/'+PCObj.newRecordId+'/e?retURL=%2F'+PCObj.newRecordId);
    System.assertEquals(ref.getUrl(),redir.getUrl());

    List<GSD_Resource__c > newItems = [Select Id From GSD_Resource__c  where Partner__c = :PCObj.newRecordId];
    System.assertEquals(newItems.size(),1);

    List<GSD_Partner_Profile_Linkage__c> newItems1 = [Select Id From GSD_Partner_Profile_Linkage__c  where Accessible_To__c = :PCObj.newRecordId];
    System.assertEquals(newItems1.size(),1);

    Test.stopTest();


   }

  }
```

Comment: Is there any trigger on GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c? If any, error might be there. Can you post debug log of the test execution?

Answer (score 0):

In your test class you do this:

```
PageReference pref = Page.GSDpartnerClone;
Test.setCurrentPage(pref);
```

In doing that, your code in the controller's try-catch block does this:

```
 GSD_Partner__c newGSDP;

 try {
     .........
     } 
     insert InsertGSDPList;

     if(!InsertGSDPList.isEmpty()){
         newRecordId = InsertGSDPList[0].id;
     }

     GSD_Resource__c OldGSDResource = [select id from  GSD_Resource__c where Partner__c = :GSDP.id limit 1];
     OldGSDResourceId = OldGSDResource.id;
     system.debug('OldGSDResourceId :'+OldGSDResourceId );
```

Right after calling the start of your test, you seem to repeat the above by calling this query:

```
GSD_Resource__c oldresource = [Select Id From GSD_Resource__c  where Partner__c = :pObj.id];
system.debug('oldresource :'+oldresource);
```

You then define a `GSD_Skill_Master__c` which I assume must be the parent or equivalent of all the `Skill_Category__c`'s since I don't see it used in your class??

You then assemble the `GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c` which does exist in your class. When you attempt to insert that is when you get your null pointer exception for trying to de-reference a null object.

When I look at the 1st query that runs in your actual controller class, at the end I see this:

```
GSD_Resource_Skills_mapping__c where Skill_Category__c = :Label.GSDResourceLang and Resource_ID__c = :OldGSDResourceId];
```

It would seem to me that your test needs to be creating these so your queries can run in the class before you declare `Test.startTest();`. In fact, this needs to be created before you run the following lines of code so your controller is ready to run:

```
Apexpages.StandardController sc = new Apexpages.standardController(pObj);
GSDPartnerCloneWithSkillsController PCObj=new GSDPartnerCloneWithSkillsController(sc);
```